# Get the most recent post with a specific custom field - Wordpress

Tags: php, custom-fields, wordpress

Im trying to reduce the amount of multiple loops I have on the homepage of a magazine website.

I want to display a post with a specific custom field differently, however I only want the first post (most recent) with that custom field. I can achieve this by creating another loop but I would like it to be included in the loop below.

For example here is my query but I need a further condition for `if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured', true)):` so it includes only the most recent post that meets this condition

```
 $fourth_query = new WP_Query($args4); 
 while($fourth_query->have_posts()) : $fourth_query->the_post();
 if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured', true)):   
     get_template_part( 'content-opinion', get_post_format() );
 else :
     get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
 endif;
 endwhile;
 wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: using argument in meta key and value to sorting your post: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: I guess I'll just have to use another loop. There are many posts with this custom field I need the most recent one and I was hoping I could do it in one loop.

Comment: yes you can get most recent post filter featured meta value in one loop.

Answer (score 1):

The function get_post_meta() returns a value not a boolean, so you have to check if the custom field exist so try with the empty() function

```
$fourth_query = new WP_Query($args4); 
 while($fourth_query->have_posts()) : $fourth_query->the_post();
 if (!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured', true))):   
     get_template_part( 'content-opinion', get_post_format() );
 else :
     get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
 endif;
 endwhile;
 wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Im looking for the most recent post that has a certain custom field, there are many posts with this custom field.

Comment: Thanks for your help but then it will only return one post there are other posts in the loop that don't not contain the custom field I would like to show. It seems I have to use two loops to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

you can merge two query

```
<?php 
    $generalQuery               = new WP_Query($args); // there is your main query 
    $queryWithCustomField       = new WP_Query($args); // there is your query with custom post and posts_per_page = 1
    $queryWithCustomField->posts = $queryWithCustomField->posts + $generalQuery->posts; // merge it now

    if ( $queryWithCustomField->have_posts() ) : while ( $queryWithCustomField->have_posts() ) : $queryWithCustomField->the_post();
        echo "your first post is ";
    endwhile;
    else:
        echo "No post Found";
    endif;
 ?>
```